# Get article text from The Guardian API

Tags: javascript, api, object

I have a problem getting the article text from the news API from The Guardian. I have a url which is something like this: http://content.guardianapis.com/search?section=technology&api-key=MYKEY
and I get a response that looks like this:

```
{
"response": {
    "status": "ok",
    "userTier": "developer",
    "total": 54530,
    "startIndex": 1,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "currentPage": 1,
    "pages": 5453,
    "orderBy": "newest",
    "results": [{
        "type": "article",
        "sectionId": "technology",
        "webTitle": "Net neutrality has its day in court – with lawyers, Christians and the Cheshire Cat",
        "webPublicationDate": "2015-12-05T12:30:06Z",
        "id": "technology/2015/dec/05/net-neutrality-has-its-day-in-court-with-lawyers-christians-and-the-cheshire-cat",
        "webUrl": "http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2015/dec/05/net-neutrality-has-its-day-in-court-with-lawyers-christians-and-the-cheshire-cat",
        "apiUrl": "http://content.guardianapis.com/technology/2015/dec/05/net-neutrality-has-its-day-in-court-with-lawyers-christians-and-the-cheshire-cat",
        "sectionName": "Technology"
    }, {
        "type": "article",
        "sectionId": "technology",
        "webTitle": "Five things we love: from a school-proof tablet to a ghostly Serbian bicycle",
        "webPublicationDate": "2015-12-05T10:00:02Z",
        "id": "technology/2015/dec/05/five-things-we-love",
        "webUrl": "http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2015/dec/05/five-things-we-love",
        "apiUrl": "http://content.guardianapis.com/technology/2015/dec/05/five-things-we-love",
        "sectionName": "Technology"
    }, {
        "type": "article",
        "sectionId": "technology",
        "webTitle": "Don’t listen to those who try to own the definition of a video game",
        "webPublicationDate": "2015-12-04T12:00:21Z",
        "id": "technology/2015/dec/04/video-games-gaming-dudegamers",
        "webUrl": "http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2015/dec/04/video-games-gaming-dudegamers",
        "apiUrl": "http://content.guardianapis.com/technology/2015/dec/04/video-games-gaming-dudegamers",
        "sectionName": "Technology"
    }]
}
}
```

and that doesn't include the article text, only a url to the news page. **My question is how do i get the article text?**

Comment: Presumably, you don't, since it wouldn't serve their business model to provide full articles in an easy-to-republish format.

Comment: Did you try to call the `apiUrl` returned? It requires an API key, maybe it's the full article.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding `show-blocks=all&` to query, for ex. returned property `"bodyTextSummary"` at url. The URL below can be broken down into:
**Basic URL:** `http://content.guardianapis.com/search?`
**Start of Search Params:** `q=`
**Search Params(all " " are substituted with "%20"):** `12%20years%20a%20slave&`
**Convert to json format:** `format=json&`
**Filter by specific tags:** `tag=film/film,tone/reviews&`
**Filter by starting date:** `from-date=2010-01-01&`
**Order by relevance:** `order-by=relevance&`
**Show Full API Hash:** `show-blocks=all&`
**Your API Key(should put your key in place of "test"):** `api-key=test`

http://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=12%20years%20a%20slave&format=json&tag=film/film,tone/reviews&from-date=2010-01-01&order-by=relevance&show-blocks=all&api-key=test

---

See http://open-platform.theguardian.com/documentation/search

Comment: @C.Kelly The query parameter should be `12%20` before `years`

Answer (score 6):

use `show-fields` key and `bodyText` key value to your URL then you will get content.

e.g: show-fields=BodyText

http://content.guardianapis.com/search?order-by=newest&show-fields=bodyText&q=politics&api-key=test